# How to rotate shape?

Tags: javascript, html, css, math

**What I've got so far:**

I'm able to draw shapes into a canvas using some simple syntax:

```
let shape = "10n10" // example shapeSyntax (*)



shapeSyntax:  "1" == "colored area"
              "0" == "blank area"
              "n" == "new line"


* So creating a simple line (width = 4, height = 1) is possible using the syntax "1111"
* Creating a square (width = 2, height = 2) is possible using the syntax "11n11" (n stands for new line)
* Creating a stair -shape would be possible using the syntax "001n011n111"
```

---

This is working really good so far. *So I've added the code so you can have a look at your own:*

**What I'd like to get:**

I'd like to develop a function `rotate(degree)` that is **able to rotate the syntax** (*not just the canvas element or something else!!!*) of any shape around `[90, 180, 270]` degrees.

So rotating a line with syntax "1111" about `90deg` should get "1n1n1n1":

```
rotate("1111", 90) // == "1n1n1n1"
```

Please have a look at this image, I'm pretty sure it will help to understand:

[image: img]

---

> What I've noticed is that rotating any shape around 180deg the syntax could just be changed by reading it backwards: `"1011" gets "1101"`. But how can I get the syntax from `0->90deg`? I got no idea how so any help how to solve this would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
// This is what I've got

// The 4 shapes where
// "1" == "colored area"
// "0" == "blank area"
// "n" == "new line"
let shapeA = "1111"
let shapeB = "10n11"
let shapeC = "111n011"
let shapeD = "00111n11100"


// This is the function to draw the shapes using *canvas*
let drawShape = function(shape, offset) {
  shape = shape.split("n");
  let shapeHeight = shape.length,
      shapeWidth = shape[0].length;
      
  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = canvas.height = 300;
  ctx.fillStyle=["red", "green", "blue", "gray", "magenta", "orange", "yellow"][Math.round(Math.random()*6)];
  
  for (let y=0; y<shapeHeight; y++) {
    for (let x=0; x<shapeWidth; x++) {
      if (shape[y][x] === "1") 
        ctx.fillRect(x*20, y*20, 20, 20);
    }
  }
  canvas.style.position = "absolute";
  canvas.style.left = offset + "%";
  document.getElementById("element").append(canvas)
}


// This is how I'm able to call the function (the second parameter is for the offset of the position)
drawShape(shapeA, 0);
drawShape(shapeB, 20);
drawShape(shapeC, 40);
drawShape(shapeD, 60);
```

```css
input {
position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 4
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="document.getElementById('element').innerHTML = ''; drawShape(this.value, 10)" placeholder="input shape syntax"/>
<div id="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert into a 2D array, rotate <strike>(transpose)</strike> that and convert back.

Edit: Thanks meowgoesthedog, transpose doesn't mean what I thought it meant.

```
var rotate = array => array[0].map( (col, i) => array.map(row => row[i]).reverse() );
var decode = str => str.split('n').map( s => s.split('') )
var encode = arr => arr.map( a => a.join('') ).join('n')

encode( rotate( decode( '01n00' ) ) )
```

Comment: @jonas00 did you even bother to at least test his code before dismissing it so completely? Is it not obvious that `str.spilt` is just a typo?

Comment: Well it certainly seemed that way. Anyways, a possible fix would be to reverse each line; this will convert the transpose (a reflection) into a 90 degree rotation. i.e. `var encode = arr => arr.map( a => a.reverse().join('')).join('n')`. Reversing the *order* of the lines will rotate 90 degrees in the opposite direction.

Comment: @jonas00 it works, the shape is rotated 90 degrees clockwise. Call `rotate` more than once to get to the other positions.